# How to only copy *complete* audio files with batch

Tags: batch-file, sox

We currently have a script that we run on our T1 loggers to convert the recordings of our agents calls **from au to mp3**. After it converts it pushes it to a network share on a server supervisors/managers ect have access to so they can pull calls as needed. We only run it at night, and due to how fast the software kills hard drives we are looking to instead pull the audio from the tappers onto the server and do the legwork there.

I am successfully copying all of the newer files over with robocopy and then renaming them with the needed information and converting them with sox clobber. However, robocopy also copies the audio files that are not done recording.

```
\\gcs1\d$\audio\live\sox.exe IF NOT EXIST %File% %NewName%.mp3 \\gcs1\d$\audio\live\mp3\
```

The problem is this won't run sox on the incomplete audio files, but if I remove IF NOT EXIST it re-copies everything which bogs it down to much. Any suggestions on what I can do to only copy complete audio files, or instead find an alternative to sox that can recognize incomplete files and only convert incomplete and newer?

Comment: are the files only mp3-s?

Comment: Do it in a loop checking the size of the file. Wait until it doesn't change for a set period of time.

Comment: What is `au` ? what should this code do: `\\gcs1\d$\audio\live\sox.exe IF NOT EXIST %File% %NewName%.mp3 \\gcs1\d$\audio\live\mp3` ? How to identify incomplete files ? What do you mean with this: `but if I remove IF NOT EXIST it re-copies everything which bogs it down to much` ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a utility called - Handle
Copyright (C) 1997-2008 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

which may help you - if you run it on the server doing the processing it may be able to tell you which files are in use by the process, and you can exclude them from the copy.

Comment: +1 for suggesting you check which files are in use, not to recommend this specific tool.